# Print doesn't show in printed array although specified

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm working a simple candy crush game for my year 1 assignment.

I am at this stage where I need to show my self-made simple marker( *box made of '|' and '_'* ) on the center of the board ( `board[5][5]` ) once the program is executed.

Here is the current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//FUNCTION: Draw the Board
int drawBoard()
{
    //Declare array size
    int board[9][9];

    //initialize variables
    int rows, columns, randomNumber, flag;

    //random number seed generator
    srand(time(NULL));

        for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 9 ; rows++ )
        {

            for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 9 ; columns++ )
            {
                flag = 0;

                do
               {
                    //generate random numbers from 2 - 8
                randomNumber = rand() %7 + 2;

                board[rows][columns] = randomNumber;

                //Checks for 2 adjacent numbers.
                if  ( board[rows][columns] == board[rows - 1][columns] || board[rows][columns] == board[rows][columns - 1] )
                    {
                        flag = 0;
                        continue;
                    }

                else
                     {
                        flag = 1;
                        printf( "  %d  ", board[rows][columns] );
                     }

                } while ( flag == 0 );

            }//end inner for-loop

            printf("\n\n");

        }//end outer for-loop

//call FUNCTION marker() to display marker around board[5][5]
marker( board[5][5] );

}//end FUNCTION drawBoard

//FUNCTION: Mark the surrounding of the number with "|" and "_" at board[5][5]
void marker( int a )
{
    printf( " _ \n" );
    printf( "|%c|\n", a );
    printf( " _ \n" );
}

int main()
{
    drawBoard();
}
```

At the end of function `drawBoard()`, I placed the code `marker( board[5][5] )`.

This should have printed the markers around the number printed at coordinate `board[5][5]`..but for some reason it displays right **after** the board has been printed.

So why doesn't it print at that coordinate although I specified it at `board[5][5]`?

What could be the problem here?

Comment: It prints after the board because you tell it to print after you tell it to print the board.

Comment: You're right @jwodder. However I really have no clue where to call the function from :(

Answer (score 0):

so in your marker function you need to pass the board and the coordinate you want to print at

```
void marker( int x, int y, int** board )
{
    board[x][y-1]="_";
    board[x-1][y]="|";
    board[x+1][y]="|";
    board[x][y+1]="_";
}
```

then after the call to marker(5,5,board), call drawboard again

my code's a bit off but that's the logic, except you need to check for the case that the  marker is at the edge of the board

in other words, you need to keep board around, and any time you make a change to it, clear the screen and print the whole board out again.

Comment: Hi @AwokeKnowing, I get this part. But the real problem is where do I call this function from? If I call marker( 5, 5, board ) at the end of function drawBoard(), the program executes with an error. I can't place it within the loop too :( I thought about using if ( board[5][5] ) call function marker( 5, 5, board ) but it also returns with an error =(

Comment: my bad, your board is an array of ints, so we can't assing "|" to it. try '|', or better yet, make it an array of chars.  Anyway, you need to separate the code that modifies the board from the code that prints the board.  first set up the board, then modify it, then print it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no persistent drawing in the way that you are doing this.  You are just printing straight to the shell/command prompt. The way that you trying to do things will not work.  You can't edit something drawn to the prompt after you have drawn it, you need to basically clear the screen and then draw again but with your indicated maker.

I don't know if you are able to use libraries in your assignment, but a very good library that WILL let you do is [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

**EDIT** *Full rewrite of answer*

---

### Drawing Things On Top of One Another In CMD

Alright, I had some downtime at work, so I wrote a project to do what you need and I'm going to post code and explain what it does and why you need it along the way.

First thin that you are going to need a basically a render buffer or a render context.  Whenever you are programming in a graphics API such as OpenGL, you don't just render straight to the screen, you render each object that you have to a buffer that rasterizes your content and turns it into pixels.  Once it's in that form, the API shoves the rendered picture onto the screen.  We are going to take a similar approach where instead of drawing to a pixel buffer on the GPU, we are going to draw to a character buffer.  Think about each character as a pixel on the screen.

**Here is a pastebin of the complete source:**
[Complete Source of Project](http://pastebin.com/jGAgEdXj)

---

**`RenderContext`**

Our class to do this will be the `RenderContext` class.  It has fields to hold width and height as well as an array of `chars` and a special char that we fill our buffer with whenever we clear it.

This class simply holds an array and functions to let us render to it.  It makes sure that when we draw to it, we are within bounds.  It is possible for an object to try to draw outside of the clipping space (off screen). However, whatever is drawn there is discarded.

```
class RenderContext {
private:
   int m_width, m_height; // Width and Height of this canvas
   char* m_renderBuffer; // Array to hold "pixels" of canvas
   char m_clearChar; // What to clear the array to

public:
   RenderContext() : m_width(50), m_height(20), m_clearChar(' ') {
      m_renderBuffer = new char[m_width * m_height];
   }
   RenderContext(int width, int height) : m_width(width), m_height(height), m_clearChar(' ') {
      m_renderBuffer = new char[m_width * m_height];
   }
   ~RenderContext();
   char getContentAt(int x, int y);
   void setContentAt(int x, int y, char val);
   void setClearChar(char clearChar);
   void render();
   void clear();
};
```

The two most important functions of this class are `setContentAt` and `render`

*`setContentAt`* is what an object calls to fill in a "pixel" value.  To make this a little more flexible, our class uses a pointer to an array of chars rather than a straight array (or even a two dimensional array).  This lets us set the size of our canvas at runtime.  Because of this, we access elements of this array with `x + (y * m_width)` which replaces a two dimensional dereference such as `arr[i][j]`

```
// Fill a specific "pixel" on the canvas
void RenderContext::setContentAt(int x, int y, char val) {
   if (((0 <= x) && (x < m_width)) && ((0 <= y) && (y < m_height))) {
      m_renderBuffer[(x + (y * m_width))] = val;
   }
}
```

*`render`* is what actually draws to the prompt.  All it does is iterate over all the "pixels" in it's buffer and place them on screen and then moves to the next line.

```
// Paint the canvas to the shell
void RenderContext::render() {
   int row, column;
   for (row = 0; row < m_height; row++) {
      for (column = 0; column < m_width; column++) {
         printf("%c", getContentAt(column, row));
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
}
```

---

**`I_Drawable`**

Our next class is an `Interface` that lets us contract with objects that they can draw to our RenderContext.  It is pure virtual because we don't want to actually be able to instantiate it, we only want to derive from it.  It's only function is *`draw`* which accepts a RenderContext.  Derived classes use this call to receive the RenderContext and then use RenderContext's setContentAt to put "pixels" into the buffer.

```
class I_Drawable {
public:
   virtual void draw(RenderContext&) = 0;
};
```

---

**`GameBoard`**

The first class to implement the I_Drawable, thus being able to render to our RenderContext, is the GameBoard class.  This is where a majority of the logic comes in.  It has fields for width, height, and a integer array that holds the values of the elements on the board.  It also has two other fields for spacing.  Since when you draw your board using your code, you have spaces between each element.  We don't need to incorporate this into the underlying structure of the board, we just need to use them when we draw.

```
class GameBoard : public I_Drawable {
private:
   int m_width, m_height; // Width and height of the board
   int m_verticalSpacing, m_horizontalSpacing; // Spaces between each element on the board
   Marker m_marker; // The cursor that will draw on this board
   int* m_board; // Array of elements on this board

   void setAtPos(int x, int y, int val);
   void generateBoard();

public:
   GameBoard() : m_width(10), m_height(10), m_verticalSpacing(5), m_horizontalSpacing(3), m_marker(Marker()) {
      m_board = new int[m_width * m_height];
      generateBoard();
   }
   GameBoard(int width, int height) : m_width(width), m_height(height), m_verticalSpacing(5), m_horizontalSpacing(3), m_marker(Marker()) {
      m_board = new int[m_width * m_height];
      generateBoard();
   }
   ~GameBoard();
   int getAtPos(int x, int y);
   void draw(RenderContext& renderTarget);
   void handleInput(MoveDirection moveDirection);
   int getWidth();
   int getHeight();
};
```

It's key functions are `generateBoard`, `handleInput`, and the derived virtual function `draw`.  However, do note that in its constructor it creates a new int array and gives it to its pointer.  Then its destructor automatically removes the allocated memory whenever the board goes away.

*`generateBoard`* is what we use to actual create the board and fill it with numbers.  It will iterate over each location on the board.  Each time, it will look at the elements directly to the left and above and store them.  Then it will generate a random number until the number it generates does not match either of the stored elements, then it stores the number in the array.  I rewrote this to get rid of the flag usage.  This function gets called during the construction of the class.

```
// Actually create the board
void GameBoard::generateBoard() {
   int row, column, randomNumber, valToLeft, valToTop;

   // Iterate over all rows and columns
   for (row = 0; row < m_height; row++) {
      for (column = 0; column < m_width; column++) {
         // Get the previous elements
         valToLeft = getAtPos(column - 1, row);
         valToTop = getAtPos(column, row - 1);

         // Generate random numbers until we have one 
         // that is not the same as an adjacent element
         do {
            randomNumber = (2 + (rand() % 7));
         } while ((valToLeft == randomNumber) || (valToTop == randomNumber));
         setAtPos(column, row, randomNumber);
      }
   }
}
```

*`handleInput`* is what deals with moving the cursor around on the board.  It's basically a freebie and your next step after getting the cursor to draw over the board.  I needed a way to test the drawing.  It accepts an enumeration that we switch on to know where to move our cursor to next.  If you maybe wanted to have your cursor wrap around the board whenever you reach an edge, you would want to do that here.

```
void GameBoard::handleInput(MoveDirection moveDirection) {
   switch (moveDirection) {
      case MD_UP:
         if (m_marker.getYPos() > 0)
            m_marker.setYPos(m_marker.getYPos() - 1);
         break;
      case MD_DOWN:
         if (m_marker.getYPos() < m_height - 1)
            m_marker.setYPos(m_marker.getYPos() + 1);
         break;
      case MD_LEFT:
         if (m_marker.getXPos() > 0)
            m_marker.setXPos(m_marker.getXPos() - 1);
         break;
      case MD_RIGHT:
         if (m_marker.getXPos() < m_width - 1)
            m_marker.setXPos(m_marker.getXPos() + 1);
         break;
   }
}
```

*`draw`* is very important because it's what gets the numbers into the RenderContext.  To summarize, it iterates over every element on the board, and draws in the correct location on the canvas placing an element under the correct "pixel".  This is where we incorporate the spacing.  Also, take care and note that we render the cursor in this function.

It's a matter of choice, but you can either store a marker outside of the GameBoard class and render it yourself in the main loop (this would be a good choice because it loosens the coupling between the GameBoard class and the Marker class.  However, since they *are* fairly coupled, I chose to let GameBoard render it.  If we used a scene graph, as we probably would with a more complex scene/game, the Marker would probably be a child node of the GameBoard so it would be similar to this implementation but still more generic by not storing an explicit Marker in the GameBoard class.

```
// Function to draw to the canvas
void GameBoard::draw(RenderContext& renderTarget) {
   int row, column;
   char buffer[8];

   // Iterate over every element
   for (row = 0; row < m_height; row++) {
      for (column = 0; column < m_width; column++) {

         // Convert the integer to a char
         sprintf(buffer, "%d", getAtPos(column, row));

         // Set the canvas "pixel" to the char at the
         // desired position including the padding
         renderTarget.setContentAt(
                 ((column * m_verticalSpacing) + 1),
                 ((row * m_horizontalSpacing) + 1),
                 buffer[0]);
      }
   }

   // Draw the marker
   m_marker.draw(renderTarget);
}
```

---

**`Marker`**

Speaking of the `Marker` class, let's look at that now.  The Marker class is actually very similar to the GameBoard class.  However, it lacks a lot of the logic that GameBoard has since it doesn't need to worry about a bunch of elements on the board.  The important thing is the draw function.

```
class Marker : public I_Drawable {
private:
   int m_xPos, m_yPos; // Position of cursor
public:
   Marker() : m_xPos(0), m_yPos(0) {
   }
   Marker(int xPos, int yPos) : m_xPos(xPos), m_yPos(yPos) {
   }
   void draw(RenderContext& renderTarget);
   int getXPos();
   int getYPos();
   void setXPos(int xPos);
   void setYPos(int yPos);
};
```

*`draw`* simply puts four symbols onto the RenderContext to outline the selected element on the board.  Take note that Marker has no clue about the GameBoard class.  It has no reference to it, it doesn't know how large it is, or what elements it holds.  You should note though, that I got lazy and didn't take out the hard coded offsets that sort of depend on the padding that the GameBoard has.  You should implement a better solution to this because if you change the padding in the GameBoard class, your cursor will be off.

Besides that, whenever the symbols get drawn, they overwrite whatever is in the ContextBuffer.  This is important because the main point of your question was how to draw the cursor on top of the GameBoard.  This also goes to the importance of draw order.  Let's say that whenever we draw our GameBoard, we drew a '=' between each element.  If we drew the cursor first and then the board, the GameBoard would draw over the cursor making it invisible.

If this were a more complex scene, we might have to do something fancy like use a depth buffer that would record the `z-index` of an element.  Then whenever we drew, we would check and see if the z-index of the new element was closer or further away than whatever was already in the RenderContext's buffer.  Depending on that, we might skip drawing the "pixel" altogether.

We don't though, so take care to order your draw calls!

```
// Draw the cursor to the canvas
void Marker::draw(RenderContext& renderTarget) {

   // Adjust marker by board spacing
   // (This is kind of a hack and should be changed)
   int tmpX, tmpY;
   tmpX = ((m_xPos * 5) + 1);
   tmpY = ((m_yPos * 3) + 1);

   // Set surrounding elements
   renderTarget.setContentAt(tmpX - 0, tmpY - 1, '-');
   renderTarget.setContentAt(tmpX - 1, tmpY - 0, '|');
   renderTarget.setContentAt(tmpX - 0, tmpY + 1, '-');
   renderTarget.setContentAt(tmpX + 1, tmpY - 0, '|');
}
```

---

**`CmdPromptHelper`**

The last class that I'm going to talk about is the CmdPromptHelper.  You don't have anything like this in your original question.  However, you will need to worry about it soon.  This class is also only useful on Windows so if you are on linux/unix, you will need to worry about dealing with drawing to the shell yourself.

```
class CmdPromptHelper {
private:
   DWORD inMode; // Attributes of std::in before we change them
   DWORD outMode; // Attributes of std::out before we change them
   HANDLE hstdin; // Handle to std::in
   HANDLE hstdout; // Handle to std::out
public:
   CmdPromptHelper();
   void reset();
   WORD getKeyPress();
   void clearScreen();
};
```

Each one of the functions is important.  The constructor gets handles to the `std::in` and `std::out` of the current command prompt.  The `getKeyPress` function returns what key the user presses **down** (key-up events are ignored).  And the `clearScreen` function clears the prompt (not really, it actually moves whatever is already in the prompt up).

*`getKeyPress`* just makes sure you have a handle and then reads what has been typed into the console.  It makes sure that whatever it is, it is a key and that it is being pressed down.  Then it returns the key code as a Windows specific enum usually prefaced by `VK_`.

```
// See what key is pressed by the user and return it
WORD CmdPromptHelper::getKeyPress() {
   if (hstdin != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
      DWORD count;
      INPUT_RECORD inrec;

      // Get Key Press
      ReadConsoleInput(hstdin, &inrec, 1, &count);

      // Return key only if it is key down
      if (inrec.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown) {
         return inrec.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode;
      } else {
         return 0;
      }

      // Flush input
      FlushConsoleInputBuffer(hstdin);
   } else {
      return 0;
   }
}
```

*`clearScreen`* is a little deceiving.  You would think that it clears out the text in the prompt.  As far as I know, it doesn't.  I'm pretty sure it actually shifts all the content up and then writes a ton of characters to the prompt to make it look like the screen was cleared.

An important concept that this function brings up though is the idea of buffered rendering.  Again, if this were a more robust system, we would want to implement the concept of double buffering which means rendering to an invisible buffer and waiting until all drawing is finished and then swap the invisible buffer with the visible one.  This makes for a much cleaner view of the render because we don't see things while they are still getting drawn.  The way we do things here, we see the rendering process happen right in front of us.  It's not a major concern, it just looks ugly sometimes.

```
// Flood the console with empty space so that we can
// simulate single buffering (I have no idea how to double buffer this)
void CmdPromptHelper::clearScreen() {
   if (hstdout != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
      CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
      DWORD cellCount; // How many cells to paint
      DWORD count; // How many we painted
      COORD homeCoord = {0, 0}; // Where to put the cursor to clear

      // Get console info
      if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hstdout, &csbi)) {
         return;
      }

      // Get cell count
      cellCount = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;

      // Fill the screen with spaces
      FillConsoleOutputCharacter(
              hstdout,
              (TCHAR) ' ',
              cellCount,
              homeCoord,
              &count
              );

      // Set cursor position
      SetConsoleCursorPosition(hstdout, homeCoord);
   }
}
```

---

**`main`**

The very last thing that you need to worry about is how to use all these things.  That's where main comes in.  You need a game loop.  Game loops are probably the most important thing in any game.  Any game that you look at will have a game loop.

The idea is:

1. Show something on screen
2. Read input
3. Handle the input
4. GOTO 1

This program is no different.  The first thing it does is create a GameBoard and a RenderContext.  It also makes a CmdPromptHelper which lets of interface with the command prompt.  After that, it starts the loop and lets the loop continue until we hit the exit condition (for us that's pressing escape).  We could have a separate class or function do dispatch input, but since we just dispatch the input to another input handler, I kept it in the main loop.  After you get the input, you send if off to the GameBoard which alters itself accordingly.  The next step is to clear the RenderContext and the screen/prompt.  Then rerun the loop if escape wasn't pressed.

```
int main() {
   WORD key;
   GameBoard gb(5, 5);
   RenderContext rc(25, 15);
   CmdPromptHelper cph;
   do {
      gb.draw(rc);
      rc.render();

      key = cph.getKeyPress();
      switch (key) {
         case VK_UP:
            gb.handleInput(MD_UP);
            break;
         case VK_DOWN:
            gb.handleInput(MD_DOWN);
            break;
         case VK_LEFT:
            gb.handleInput(MD_LEFT);
            break;
         case VK_RIGHT:
            gb.handleInput(MD_RIGHT);
            break;
      }
      rc.clear();
      cph.clearScreen();
   } while (key != VK_ESCAPE);
}
```

---

After you have taken into consideration all of these things, you understand why and where you need to be drawing your cursor.  It's not a matter of calling a function after another, you need to composite your draws.  You can't just draw the GameBoard and then draw the Marker.  At least not with the command prompt.  I hope this helps.  It definitely alleviated the down time at work.

Comment: Hi @zero298, unfortunately this assignment doesn't allow us to use ncurses :( I fully understand your concept of clearing and then drawing again with the indicated marker. However the real problem is where do I call the function marker from?

Comment: @SamLiew Ok, full edit rewrite.  If this doesn't answer your question, I don't know what will.