# Returning a value from a function to another function

Tags: c++, function

I'm making a program where a user can move their character (the number 1) throughout an array that is printed to the screen. I ran into trouble when i tried checking to see if the next position was open in my moveRight function.

I want to return the value of the part of the array which is one space to the right of the 1. The reason I am trying to return the value of the next spot of the array is because I want to return that value to my drawBoard function so I can use that value to reprint the board making the one in that position. How would i return mB[i+1] -(the next value to the right of the 1) to my drawBoard function?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "PlayerM.h"

using namespace std;
class Player {
public:
   Player::Player(int b[]) //create a constructer to copy the values of b into mB
   {
      // copy b into the member array
      for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
         mB[i] = b[i];
      }
   }

   int moveUp();
   void moveDown();
   int moveRight();
   void moveLeft();
private:
   int mB[16];

};
int Player::moveUp() {
   return 0;
}
void Player::moveDown() {

}
int Player::moveRight() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) //find the players pos on aray
   {
      if (mB[i] == 1 && i < 3) //if the player is eligible to move
      {
         mB[i] = 0;
         mB[i + 1] = 1;
         return mB[i + 1];
      }
   }
}
void Player::moveLeft() {
}
int drawBoard(int boardArray[16]) //draw the game board
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) //use a for loop to simply draw the game board (4x4)
   {
      cout << boardArray[i]; //ouput the storage id of the array
      if (i == 3 || i == 7 || i == 11 || i == 15) //every 4 lines begin new line
      {
         cout << "\n";
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
int main() {
   int bArray[16] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; //create an array [16]
   drawBoard(bArray); //send the aray to drawBoard ()
   Player p(bArray); //send bArray to the p constructer
   char m;
   cin >> m;

   if (m == 'W') {
      p.moveRight();
   }

   char f;
   cin >> f;
}
```

Comment: Please tidy up the formatting/indentation

Comment: sorry. should be good now? @EdHeal

Comment: "mB[i+1] -(the next value to the right of the 1)" to me would just be "mB[i+1]-mB[i+2]"

Comment: For reference, nearly all of the comments in this code are useless -- they only tell you stuff you'd already instantly know from looking at the code.  Reserve comments for stuff that's not obvious, like the *reason* you're doing what you're doing the way you're doing it.

Comment: @user3150762 - You do like your blank lines :-)

Comment: If you plan to redraw the board with a '1' in that position, then what difference does it make what character *used to* be there?

Comment: I dont need to know what character used to be there. I need to know if the current position is eligible for a right move.  @Beta

Comment: So how do i return the mB[i+1] value to my drawBoard func?

Comment: I gave a really long answer about `cmd` grid games, check this out as it will give you a lot of insight about gridded games and the `cmd` prompt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551474/print-doesnt-show-in-printed-array-although-specified/19551790#19551790

Comment: Why not return a boolean (a yes-or-no), so that `main can decide whether to call `drawBoard` again? There is no reason for `drawBoard` to know about what the `Player` was trying to do.

Comment: thanks. seems like that would help if i was more experienced. i have only been programming c++ for like 2 weeks. so i dont have alot of basic knowledge. @zero298

Comment: I'd suggest having only one array, not two (`bArray` and `mB`). That'll make other decisions easier.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int Player::moveRight() {
>    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) //find the players pos on aray
>    {
>       if (mB[i] == 1 && i < 3) //if the player is eligible to move
>       {
>          mB[i] = 0;
>          mB[i + 1] = 1;
>          return mB[i + 1];
>       }
>    }
> }
> ```

I think you want the following (given that the board is 4x4):

```
int Player::moveRight() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) //find the players pos on aray
   {
      if (mB[i] == 1 && (i%4) < 3) //if the player is eligible to move
      {
         mB[i] = 0;
         mB[i + 1] = 1;
         return mB[i + 1];
      }
   }
}
```

What changed: `i < 3` to `(i%4) < 3`